# Pass Kendo Template as Variable to Template Javascript Function (#=addFileExtensionIcon(#=DocType#)#)

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to Pass Kendo Template as Variable to Template Javascript Function to inject return of the JS function into the span's class. ( object is to dynamically set the icon ). 
Such as: `#=addFileExtensionIcon(#=DocType#)#`

Current iteration is causing the loading gif to persist indefinitely...

Can I do This & if not what are my options?

```
@*//WF ITEM ATTACHMENTS TEMPLATE*@
<script id="itemAttachmentsTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">  
    <div class="attachment">

        <span class='k-icon #=addFileExtensionIcon(#=DocType#)#'></span>

        <h3>FILE NAME</h3>
        <h3>#=DocType#</h3>
        <h3>#=CreatedByUserName#</h3>
        <div class="btn btn-link" id="">
            <span class="k-icon k-i-download"> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Js:

```
function addFileExtensionIcon(extension) {
    switch (extension) {
        case '.jpg':
        case '.img':
        case '.png':
        case '.gif':
            return ".k-i-image";
        case '.doc':
        case '.docx':
            return ".k-i-file-doc";
        case '.xls':
        case '.xlsx':
            return ".k-i-file-xls";
        case '.pdf':
            return ".k-i-file-pdf";
        case '.zip':
        case '.rar':
            return ".k-i-file-zip";
        default:
            return ".k-i-file";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this.

```
<script id="itemAttachmentsTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">  
<div class="attachment">

    <span class='k-icon #=addFileExtensionIcon(DocType)#'></span>

    <h3>FILE NAME</h3>
    <h3>#=DocType#</h3>
    <h3>#=CreatedByUserName#</h3>
    <div class="btn btn-link" id="">
        <span class="k-icon k-i-download"> </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you!